# Facebook SDK manually set session token

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack to authorise a user via either credentials (username or password) or Facebook.

I make a call to the ServiceStack auth endpoint /auth/facebook and set a few headers, and pass this to a UIWebView that does the needed redirects and gets the user to authorise on the FB website.

Once its complete I am redirected back to my site within the UIWebView and am left with a ServiceStack session ID and a few details from Facebook:

```
COOKIENAME: c_user VALUE: 55186xxxx  DOMAIN facebook.com
COOKIENAME: csm VALUE: 2 DOMAIN facebook.com
COOKIENAME: datr VALUE: y3IrWPvRAMADxxxxxxvM0-Mz DOMAIN facebook.com
COOKIENAME: fr VALUE: 0l7ecy1TXvq0vRVNo.AWUI6Nxxxxxx DOMAIN facebook.com
COOKIENAME: lu VALUE: Rg83BbxxxxEl_i9k1VeG3g DOMAIN facebook.com
COOKIENAME: s VALUE: Aa7j4xxxNa0.BYK3Lq DOMAIN facebook.com
COOKIENAME: sb VALUE: 6XIrWxxxxSivEPDDT3X DOMAIN facebook.com
COOKIENAME: xs VALUE: 25%3ASYAc8Zxxxx%3A2%3A1479242473%3A8823 DOMAIN facebook.com
```

Is there anyway I can take any of this info and register it with FBSDKAccessToken() or similar to get the Facebook SDK working in Swift?

Comment: Facebook Platform Policy say that you are never allowed to ask for username or password from the user. So no there are no API that would do that. You need to use Facebook Login

Comment: I am not asking for a login.  ServiceStack does the behind the scenes work that any other website login uses, I just want to use the info that service stack returns to be able to use the FB SDK.  ServiceStack does work with the Facebook Login SDK

Comment: I'm saying it is not allowed. Facebook Terms of Service also say that users are not allowed to share their passwords with your service.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get whats not allowed? Its standard Facebook sign in, it works via website perfectly, it works in the mobile app I am just trying to link the Facebook connection to the Facebook SDK.  I can sort of get it working with:         `FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrent(FBSDKAccessToken(tokenString: "xxxx", permissions:permissions , declinedPermissions: nil, appID: "xxx", userID: "xxxx", expirationDate: NSDate.distantFuture, refreshDate: NSDate.distantFuture))`  I just need to work out how to get the token string from the cookies the sign in leaves behind

Comment: There is no way to get a token from cookies or username + password. That is the part that is not allowed. You have to use Facebook Login where the user manually login or approve permissions to the app.

Comment: Thanks. Got it figured eventually.  I needed to change how the ServiceStack redirect works, when Facebook redirects back to Servicestack, the access token is in the URL.  I can then take that and pass it to the tokenString here `FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrent(FBSDKAccessToken(tokenString: "xxxx", permissions:permissions , declinedPermissions: nil, appID: "xxx", userID: "xxxx", expirationDate: NSDate.distantFuture, refreshDate: NSDate.distantFuture))` and it works as expected then